# How to parse the drop down list and get the all the links for the pdf using Beautiful Soup in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pdf-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the pdf links from the drop down this [website](https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/english#). I want to scrape just the Guideline Values (CVC) drop down. Following is the code that i used but did not succeed

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req_ses = requests.Session()
igr_get_base_response = req_ses.get("https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/english#")

soup = BeautifulSoup(igr_get_base_response.text)

def matches_block(tag):
    return matches_dropdown(tag) and tag.find(matches_text) != None

def matches_dropdown(tag):
    return tag.name == 'li' and tag.has_attr('class') and 'dropdown-toggle' in tag['class']

def matches_text(tag):
    return tag.name == 'a' and tag.get_text()

for li in soup.find_all(matches_block):
    for ul in li.find_all('ul', class_='dropdown-toggle'):
        for a in ul.find_all('a'):
            if a.has_attr('href'):
                print (a['href'])
```

any suggestion would be great help !

Edit: Adding part of HTML below:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">



        <li class="">
            <a href="https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/english" title="Home" class="shome"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i></a>
        </li>





        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="RTI Act">RTI Act <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">

                <!-- <li> -->
                <li class="">
                    <a href=" https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/page/RTI+Act/Yadagiri+./en " title="Yadagiri .">Yadagiri .
                    </a>

                </li>

                <!-- </li> -->

                <!-- <li>
```

Comment: Due to GEO location, the site not accessible from my end.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη i've tried to add the source code, see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i used the following approach to complete the above mentioned part:

```
def make_sqlite_dict_from_parsed_row(district_value, sro_value, pdf_file_link):
    sqlite_dict = {
        "district_value": district_value,
        "sro_value": sro_value,
        "pdf_file_link": pdf_file_link.strip().replace(' ', '%20'),
        "status": "PENDING"
    }
    sqlite_dict['hsh'] = get_hash(sqlite_dict, IGR_SQLITE_HSH_TUP)
    return sqlite_dict

li_element_list = home_response_soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'dropdown-submenu'})
parsed_row_list=[]

for ele in li_element_list:
    district_value = ele.find('a', {'class': 'dropdown-toggle'}).get_text().strip()
    sro_pdf_a_tags = ele.find_all('a', attrs={'target': '_blank'})

    if len(sro_pdf_a_tags) >=1:
        for sro_a_tag in sro_pdf_a_tags:
            sqlite_dict = make_sqlite_dict_from_parsed_row(
                district_value,
                sro_a_tag.get_text(strip=True),
                sro_a_tag.get('href')
            )
            parsed_row_list.append(sqlite_dict)
            
    else:
        print("District: ", district_value, "'s pdf is corrupted")
```

this will give a proper_pdf_link, sro_name and disctrict_name

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to get the links of all the PDF files that you need.

I have selected the `<a>` tags whose `href` matches with the pattern - *see `patt` in code*. This pattern is common to all the PDF files that you need.

Now you have all the links to the PDF files in `links` list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/english#'

resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')


a = soup.find('a', attrs= {'title': 'Guidelines Value (CVC)'})
lst = a.parent()

links = []

patt = 'https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/storage/pdf-files/Guidelines Value/'

for i in lst:
    temp = i.find('a')
    if temp:
        if patt in temp['href']:
            links.append(temp['href'].strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

I have first find `ul_tag` in which all the data is available now from that `find_all` method on `a` where it contains `.pdf` href with attrs having `target:_blank` so from it we can extract only `.pdf` links

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res=requests.get("https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/english#")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
ul_tag=soup.find("ul",class_="nav navbar-nav")
a_tag=ul_tag.find_all("a",attrs={"target":"_blank"})

for i in a_tag:
    print(i.get_text(strip=True))
    print(i.get("href").strip())
```

Output:

```
SRO Chikkaballapur
https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/storage/pdf-files/Guidelines Value/chikkaballapur  sro.pdf
SRO Gudibande
https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/storage/pdf-files/Guidelines Value/gudibande sro.pdf
SRO Shidlaghatta
https://igr.karnataka.gov.in/storage/pdf-files/Guidelines Value/shidlagatta sro.pdf
SRO Bagepalli
....
```